# Python Memory Management: How to determine if a file is empty without checking for empty bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management

I'm looking to make memory improvements. Is there a better way to check if a file is empty besides what I currently have (checking if filepath exists and size is zero bytes)?

`if os.path.exists(file_path) and os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0`

Comment: that shouldn't take a lot of memory. Why do you think this the problem is in this line?

Comment: Why not using ```os.path.getsize()``` function to directly retrieves the file size without accessing the complete metadata.

Comment: I'm not familiar with memory management so I want to test different options out. Will try os.path.getsize(). Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHao That does the same thing: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13aefd175e3c04529251f175c23cb3ed88451fd0/Lib/genericpath.py#L60